# How to find the elements of an array that are not in another array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I currently have a MATLAB range `j=1:200` and an array `m=96:106`.

I'm trying to define a new array that will have all the values in `j` that aren't in `m`.

I've tried using

```
j_prime = (j~=m)
```

but that doesn't work for a range of numbers. If `m` was just a number like 101, this works.  I'm sure I just don't know MATLAB enough to know a good way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Just found the `setdiff` command so using `setdiff(j,m)` will result in what I'm looking for!